# Where to pack native libs in Jar

Tags: java, maven, gradle, java-native-interface

I'm building a library that uses native code (`*.dll` on Windows, `lib*.so` on Linux). Where should I pack those files in JAR? Right now when I'm running example that uses native API (thorough) my library, I need to add param `-Djava.library.path=<path_to_dll_or_so>`.

Can I somehow show java where to look for library path?

For packing I'm using gradle `build` and `jar`

Comment: Maybe that link will help you: https://github.com/adamheinrich/native-utils